# Pylint cannot import local modules

Tags: python-3.x, pylint

My project has the following structure:

```
some_dir/
   __init__.py
   main_prog.py
   support
       __init__.py
       some_file.py
```

The code in `main_prog.py` has the following:

```
from support.some_file import SomeClass
```

All works correctly but `pylint` fails to import `SomeClass`.

What needs to be done? I am running in a terminal (not using VSCode) and would expect `pylint' to simply work the same way as Python 3.8.10

Note I am using a **venv** which has the following packages:

```
astroid==2.11.6
dill==0.3.5.1
HiYaPyCo==0.5.0
isort==5.10.1
Jinja2==3.1.2
lazy-object-proxy==1.7.1
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
mccabe==0.7.0
platformdirs==2.5.2
pylint==2.14.3
PyYAML==5.4.1
tomli==2.0.1
tomlkit==0.11.0 
typing_extensions==4.2.0
wrapt==1.14.1
```

Other answers on StackOverflow do not appear to cover this simple scenario.

Comment: If `support` is intended to be a top-level package, why is there an `__init__.py` file in `some_dir`? That makes it seem like you intend `some_dir` to be package, in which case `support.py` would correspond to the module `some_dir.support`

Comment: @Brian, that has fixed it - the project is one I have inherited - I wasn't sure if it was the venv, the os or something else - turned out it was something else. If you add your info as an answer I will accept it –